# Dynamic Library causes error when added to setup.py file (on Mac OS.X)

Tags: c++, python, opencv, cython, distutils

I have a dynamic library, built in cpp that actually works in cpp but is causing much headache when I try to import it from a python class. The error appears simply when I add the lib to my setup.py file. Error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Marcelo-Salloum:python_cpp_interface marcelosalloum$ python userect.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "userect.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rectangle import Rectangle
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/marcelosalloum/Projects/CppOpenCV/python_cpp_interface/rectangle.so, 2): Symbol not found: __XEatDataWords
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libXext.6.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libX11.6.dylib
 in /opt/local/lib/libXext.6.dylib
```

Setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    name = 'DyCppInterface',
    version = '1.0',
    author = 'Marcelo Salloum dos Santos',
    # The ext modules interface the cpp code with the python one:
    ext_modules=[
        Extension("rectangle",
            sources=["rectangle.pyx", "cpp_rect.cpp"], # Note, you can link against a c++ library instead of including the source
            include_dirs=[".","source", "/opt/local/include/opencv", "/opt/local/include"],
            language="c++",
            # extra_link_args = ['-arch x86_64'],
            # extra_link_args = ['-arch i386', '-arch x86_64'],
            library_dirs=['/usr/local/lib', 'source'],
            runtime_library_dirs=['/Users/marcelosalloum/Projects/CppOpenCV/python_cpp_interface/source'],
            libraries=['LibCppOpenCV'])
    ],
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

It is known that This *.so file uses a c++ OpenCV library. Before adding this lib to my shared library, everything was working perfectly.

- How to figure out what is causing the error?
- Should I try with a static library instead of a dynamic one?
- P.S.: my **DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = ~/Projects/CppOpenCV/python_cpp_interface/source/:/usr/local/mysql/lib/**

Comment: The problem seems to have nothing to do with your code, and everything to do with your X11 installation. Your MacPorts `libXext` is looking for the symbol `__XEatDataWords` from `libX11`, and it's not there. You may be "at fault" by indirectly calling the code that calls that function, but really, the fault is either (a) your MacPorts `libXext` doesn't match your MacPorts `libX11`, or (b) your MacPorts `libXext` is linking against a different (e.g., Apple) `libX11`.

Comment: Switching to a static library could theoretically hide the problem (if you're not actually referencing the bad function, it may get stripped out of the static link entirely), but really, you need to fix whatever's wrong with your setup.

Comment: Finally, I don't think this is C++-related at all. You can test that pretty easily: Write and compile a simple C wrapper around the C++ library, then wrap that C wrapper in Cython, and if you still have the problem, it's not Cython and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of abarnert, I solved the problem updating and upgrading MacPorts. As abarnert observed, there was a linking problem between `/opt/local/lib/libXext.6.dylib` and `/opt/local/lib/libX11.6.dylib`.

So I did:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port upgrade outdated
```